# Bluetooth in Terminal

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, bluetooth

I want to see the Bluetooth adapter details in terminal without using Bluetooth GUI. Initially Bluetooth is turned off both in terminal and GUI.

**My commands for different functions in Terminal**

View status of Bluetooth (it will show active/inactive and status in some cases, and just active/inactive in some other cases)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
```

Turn on Bluetooth

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

Turn off Bluetooth

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
```

View the Bluetooth adapter details

```
hciconfig
```

I can see the adapter details with the help of Bluetooth GUI in Settings GUI.

***I researched the status of Bluetooth in different cases by doing following steps in order:***

*1. Turn on Bluetooth via terminal*

- Status = "Running"
- Active = "active (running)"
- Bluetooth adapter details: Doesn't display anything

*2. Turn off Bluetooth via terminal*

- Status = Not shown
- Active = "inactive (dead)"
- Bluetooth adapter details: Doesn't display anything

*3. Turn on Bluetooth via GUI*

- Status = "Running"
- Active = "active (running)"
- Bluetooth adapter details: Shows the adapter details

*4. Turn off Bluetooth via terminal, but doesn't change in GUI*

- Status = "Quitting"
- Active = "inactive (dead)"
- Bluetooth adapter details: Shows the adapter details

*5. Turn on Bluetooth via terminal*

- Status = "Running"
- Active = "active (running)"
- Bluetooth adapter details: Shows the adapter details

*6. Turn off Bluetooth via terminal, but doesn't change in GUI*

- Status = "Quitting"
- Active = "inactive (dead)"
- Bluetooth adapter details: Shows the adapter details

*7. Turn off Bluetooth in GUI*

- Status = Not shown
- Active = "inactive (dead)"
- Bluetooth adapter details: Doesn't display anything

Can someone please help me what's wrong in my commands? Also, why it works fine along with GUI? What does GUI actually do?

Comment: Questions that are not about **writing software** should be on a different StackExchange site. In this case, consider [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: (Also, we can't say anything useful about your GUI without knowing which one it is -- lots of different Linux distributions have their own settings GUIs, and nothing included in this question specifies your distro, desktop environment, etc; similarly, `/etc/init.d/bluetooth` is itself distribution-specific).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this tool a try:

```
bluetoothctl
```

Here is the installation guide:
 (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth#Installation)

it gives you a lot of posibilities:

```
Menu main:
Available commands:
-------------------
advertise                                         Advertise Options Submenu
scan                                              Scan Options Submenu
gatt                                              Generic Attribute Submenu
list                                              List available controllers
show [ctrl]                                       Controller information
select <ctrl>                                     Select default controller
devices                                           List available devices
paired-devices                                    List paired devices
system-alias <name>                               Set controller alias
reset-alias                                       Reset controller alias
power <on/off>                                    Set controller power
pairable <on/off>                                 Set controller pairable mode
discoverable <on/off>                             Set controller discoverable mode
agent <on/off/capability>                         Enable/disable agent with given capability
default-agent                                     Set agent as the default one
advertise <on/off/type>                           Enable/disable advertising with given type
set-alias <alias>                                 Set device alias
scan <on/off>                                     Scan for devices
info [dev]                                        Device information
pair [dev]                                        Pair with device
trust [dev]                                       Trust device
untrust [dev]                                     Untrust device
block [dev]                                       Block device
unblock [dev]                                     Unblock device
remove <dev>                                      Remove device
connect <dev>                                     Connect device
disconnect [dev]                                  Disconnect device
menu <name>                                       Select submenu
version                                           Display version
quit                                              Quit program
exit                                              Quit program
help                                              Display help about this program
```

you can even drill down into the advertise policies and more:

```
# menu advertise 
Menu advertise:
Available commands:
-------------------
uuids [uuid1 uuid2 ...]                           Set/Get advertise uuids
service [uuid] [data=xx xx ...]                   Set/Get advertise service data
manufacturer [id] [data=xx xx ...]                Set/Get advertise manufacturer data
tx-power [on/off]                                 Show/Enable/Disable TX power to be advertised
name [on/off/name]                                Configure local name to be advertised
appearance [on/off/value]                         Configure custom appearance to be advertised
duration [seconds]                                Set/Get advertise duration
timeout [seconds]                                 Set/Get advertise timeout
clear [uuids/service/manufacturer/config-name...] Clear advertise config
back                                              Return to main menu
version                                           Display version
quit                                              Quit program
exit                                              Quit program
help                                              Display help about this program
```

That is a lot of information you can pull (and set) directly.

Comment: See the "about programming [as described in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" criteria in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).